# Enable only fullscreen feature in flash version of MediaElement.js

Tags: html, flash, video, fullscreen, mediaelement.js

I am using **MediaElement** player plugin in my website. I want users to have control only over the **fullscreen** mode of video. So I have enabled only the fullscreen feature of the MediaElement player. 
In the non-full screen mode in **flash** I am able to see only fullscreen button but as soon I go to fullscreen mode all the controls play/pause, progress, current etc. are visible.
I am able to get this working for **HTML5version** of video for both fullscreen and non fullscreen mode. Here is the code snippet which I have used to attach MediaElement to the video.

```
$(".video").mediaelementplayer({
    defaultVideoWidth: 640,
    defaultVideoHeight: 480,
    features:['fullscreen'],
    clickToPlayPause:false,
    success: function (mediaelement, dom) {}
});
```

Please let me know if there is a way this feature works in fullscreen mode for Flash players.

--Thanks in advance